# Stop the background service which contains the LocationManager

Tags: android

I am starting my background service from the MainActivity with `startService(intent)` which sends the location of the user to the server. I want to enable the user to stops this service (also stoping `requestLocationUpdates` of firing the data from the onLocationChanged method) if he does not wish it by clicking button in the Menu.
I have tried the code in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method  but the service it still works when I click button.

How can I stop this service?

**MainActivity:**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.route_available);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
    startService(i);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.disconnect_id:
        System.out.println("test onCreateOptionsMenu was invoked.");

        // Stop the service when the Menu button clicks.
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
        stopService(i);

        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Tracking Service class:**

```
public class TrackingService extends Service {

 ....
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Updation has started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        Log.v("X", "Response:in onStartCommand()");

        detectLocation();
        stopSelf();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void detectLocation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inside detectlocation()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll = new MyLocationListener(this);
        // location updates: at least 0 meter and 60 seconds change.
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30 * 1000, 0,
                ll);

        Log.v("X", "Response:After lm1.requestLocationUpdates ");
        enableGPS(lm);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the way you have it coded now, your Service isn't really doing anything.

Because you have registered your `MyLocationListener` instance as the LocationListener, stopping the Service doesn't do anything.

Also, since you call `stopSelf()` in `onStartCommand()`, you're stopping the Service immediately every time it starts.

I would recommend making the Service the LocationListener, and don't call `stopSelf()` in `onStartCommand()`
.
Also, override `onDestroy()` in the Service, and explicitly call `removeUpdates()` in order to ensure your app releases it's request to keep the GPS radio active.

Something like this:

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements LocationListener{

    LocationManager lm; //make instance variable

    //....
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Updation has started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        Log.v("X", "Response:in onStartCommand()");

        detectLocation();
        //stopSelf(); //don't stop the service here
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    private void detectLocation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inside detectlocation()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //LocationListener ll = new MyLocationListener(this);

        // location updates: at least 0 meter and 60 seconds change.
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30 * 1000, 0,
                this);

        Log.v("X", "Response:After lm1.requestLocationUpdates ");
        enableGPS(lm);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //put your location changed code here

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

}
```

Comment: But how to invoke the `onDestroy()` in the TrackingService from the `onOptionsItemSelected()` in the MainActivity? I have to implement it as an option the menu.

Comment: @light `onDestroy()` will be called when you call `stopService(i)`, so with these changes to your Service, you should be able to keep your MainActivity code as it is in your question.  As for `LocationListener ll`, it's not needed, since you just use `this` as the LocationListener reference in the Service.

Comment: is there recommended way to restart the service after stopping it?

Comment: @light, you would just need to call `startService()` just as you currently do in `onCreate()`, and you could do that from another menu item if you want to give the user the option to re-start location tracking. (or, you could just change the one menu item to be a toggle on/off, and change the text each time the user chooses to start or stop the location tracking).

Comment: Please can you take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851986/ondestroy-is-not-being-called-after-going-main-map-main-map-with-stopping-s ?